# Habilitar permiso de ubicación en navegadores para localhost

Tags: reactjs, geolocalización, chrome

Siempre utilicé sin ningún problema los servicios de ubicación con mis apps en reactJS. Pero al re instalar el SO no puedo acceder a los mismos. No puedo habilitar la misma, ya que el navegador no me lo permite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la siguiente función accedo a la localización:

```
const getLocation = async () => {
  
  try {
      Geolocation.watchPosition()
      const position = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      posicion=position.coords.latitude +"/"+ position.coords.longitude
      return posicion;

  } catch (e) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La API de Geolocation del navegador solo permite acceso desde dominios con certificado de seguridad, es decir con conexión HTTPS.

Siendo como dices en localhost no debe ser una conexión con este protocolo seguro y por tanto el propio navegador te impide poder utilizar esta API.

Comment: Gracias pero ¿Cómo se implementa un certificado en el localhost?